# How to add response json from retrofit2 to pojo class

Tags: java, json, retrofit2

I have response json

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "reckBP6Wgo6NP02xF",
      "fields": {
        "Thumbnail": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5d/2f/10/5d2f10fdd14ec94a0b9fe5b08b9c49e8.jpg"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-03-21T22:48:47.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I have created a pojo class

**ResponseWall**

```java
public class ResponseWall{

    private List<Record> records = null;

}
```

**Record**

```java
public class Record {
    private String id;
    private Fields fields;
    private String createdTime;

}
```

**Fields**

```java
public class Fields {

    private String Thumbnail;

}
```

**Function onResponse**

```
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseWall> call, Response<ResponseWall> response) {
            Log.d("d", "getting response.........\n" + response);
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                if (response.body().getRecords().size() > 0){
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < response.body().getRecords().size(); i++) {
                        String id = response.body().getRecords().get(i).getId();
                        String url = response.body().getRecords().get(i).getFields().getThumbnail();
                        String date = response.body().getRecords().get(i).getCreatedTime();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            }
```

how to add response.body to pojo class?

Comment: What do you mean by `add response.body to pojo class`? You have already converted `response.body()` to POJO object.

Comment: i want to show response.body to recyclerview

Comment: ResponseWall responseWall = response.body()